# How to get one row from a many to many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: tables]

```
id name   (sources)
-- ----
1  first
2  second

source_id tag_id   (source_tags)
--------- ------
1         1
1         2
2         3

source_id tag_id exception_value   (source_tag_exceptions)
--------- ------ ---------------
1         2      1
1         1      2 

id name   (tags)
-- ----
1  tag_one
2  tag_two
3  tag_three
```

[sql import file](http://www.filedropper.com/4-29-15import_1)
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8630/1/0)

I have a one to many relationship for sources and source tags. I'm looking to show the source_tag_exceptions.exception_value if there are any available. When I do a simple LEFT JOIN, I get one row for each source_tag. I understand why, but how do I show only one row for the source_tag_exceptions and still show all source rows? If there are multiple rows, I would prefer to see the value 1 over any others...

This is the query I am using that returns multiple rows

```
SELECT sources.name, source_tag_exceptions.exception_value
FROM sources
LEFT JOIN source_tags ON source_tags.source_id = sources.id
LEFT JOIN source_tag_exceptions ON source_tag_exceptions.source_id = sources.id AND source_tag_exceptions.tag_id = source_tags.tag_id
```

Current Results

```
name   exception_value
----   ---------------
first  1
first  2
second NULL
```

Target Results

```
name   exception_value
----   ---------------
first  1
second NULL
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1`? or did I misunderstand the question

Comment: `WHERE source_tag_exceptions.exception_value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: If providing DDLs, do so as an sqlfiddle, or just paste here. Don't link to a file.

Comment: I still want to show a distinct list of all source rows, but a computed column for exception_value. LIMIT 1 would should me only 1 row and WHERE exception_value IS NOT NULL doesn't wouldn't show me all source rows either.

Comment: really? what is wrong with result with my `WHERE` clause? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8630/2

Comment: That shows one the "first" source row 2 times. I'm looking to show all source rows. A result set with "first, 1" and "second, NULL"

Comment: why **"first, 1"** not **"first, 2"** do you need any? min? max? avg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8630/11

```
SELECT sources.name, MAX(source_tag_exceptions.exception_value)
FROM sources
LEFT JOIN source_tags 
ON source_tags.source_id = sources.id
LEFT JOIN source_tag_exceptions 
  ON source_tag_exceptions.source_id = sources.id 
    AND source_tag_exceptions.exception_value =1
  AND source_tag_exceptions.tag_id = source_tags.tag_id
LEFT JOIN tags
ON tags.id = source_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY sources.name
```

Comment: That doesn't show all source rows. That removes source rows with NULL exception_values.

Comment: which rows do you need? you've had `second` before, but said you don't want to see it?

Comment: Thanks, I added my target results to the question.